# Webpack DllBundlesPlugin cannot find module 'primeng'

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, primeng, webpack-plugin

I have an Angular2 (4.0.0-rc.2) app with Webpack configured to use HMR feature, also I use webpack-dll-bundles-plugin to make dlls in Dev environment and I want to use PrimeNG components. So I need to have primeng package as a vendor dependency in DllBundlesPlugin, but when I add 'primeng' into vendor bundle webpack compilation fails with this error:

```
DLL: Checking if DLLs are valid.
npm : { Error: Cannot find module 'primeng'
At line:1 char:1
+ npm run build:dev
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ({ Error: Cannot find module 'primeng':String) 
[], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
at DllBundlesControl.getPackageJsonPath
```

My config is as follows:

```js
plugins: [
    new DllBundlesPlugin({
        bundles: {
            polyfills: [
                'core-js',
                {
                    name: 'zone.js',
                    path: 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
                },
                {
                    name: 'zone.js',
                    path: 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js'
                }
            ],
            vendor: [
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/forms',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/router',
                'primeng',
                'rxjs',
            ]
        },
        dllDir: './wwwroot/dist',
        webpackConfig: webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
            devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
            plugins: []
        })
    })
]
```

I've also tried 'primeng/primeng', but then I get:

```js
Error: Package name mismatch, Expected primeng/primeng but found primeng
```

So, is it possible somehow to use DllBundlesPlugin with PrimeNG ?